# How do I make a custom Dropdown Menu and avoid pushing other widgets down in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to build a custom Dropdown Menu, but the list that appears once I tap on it, pushes down every other widget in the Column, instead of going over other items like Flutter's Dropdown Menu does.

How do I make it behave like Flutter's Dropdown Menu? That is to say, how do I make it so that the list of elements goes over any other item that may be below it, without pushing all the elements below?

I would like to make it a reusable Widget, so I would like to avoid creating a general Stack behind the whole app.

[image: This is the desired behaviour]

[image: This is my current code]

```
class CustomPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomPicker({
    super.key,
    this.label,
    required this.selectedValue,
    required this.values,
    this.updateValue,
  });

  String? label;
  dynamic selectedValue;
  List<dynamic> values;
  Function? updateValue;

  @override
  State<CustomPicker> createState() => _CustomPickerState();
}

class _CustomPickerState extends State<CustomPicker> {
  bool showList = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) => Stack(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: paddingAdjuster(8)),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            if (widget.label != null)
                              SizedBox(
                                width: orientation == Orientation.landscape
                                    ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6
                                    : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.5,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: paddingAdjuster(10)),
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.label!.toUpperCase(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: widget.label == null
                                    ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                                    : widget.orientation == Orientation.landscape
                                        ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3
                                        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.9,
                                height: 55,
                                child: 
                                  GestureDetector(
                                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            showList = !showList;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.5),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          ),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: paddingAdjuster(10)),
                                            child: Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                    valueParser(widget.selectedValue),
                                                    maxLines: 1,
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  )),
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: paddingAdjuster(10)),
                                                    child: SizedBox(
                                                      height: 55,
                                                      child: Icon(
                                                        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        size: fontSizeAdjuster(36),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  if (showList == true)
                    CardStyle(
                      borderCorners: const [BorderCorners.all],
                      isLast: false,
                      orientation: orientation,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              for (var element in widget.values)
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: paddingAdjuster(10)),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        element,
                                      ),
                                      if (widget.values.last != element)
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: paddingAdjuster(5)),
                                          child: Divider(thickness: 1, height: 1, color: Colors.grey),
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              )),
    ;
  }
```